# Do While Loop in C (CS50)

Tags: c, do-while, cs50

I am currently trying to do the CS50 course. I am trying to make a do-while loop for the 1st problem set, but i throws back an error. Help would be great, thanks!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    do
    {
        printf("Enter a positive integer no greater than 23: \n");
        int n = get_int();
    }
    while ( int n < 0 || int n > 23);

}
```

$clang mario.c

```
mario.c:12:13: error: expected expression
    while ( int n < 0 || int n > 23);
            ^
mario.c:12:13: error: expected ')'
mario.c:12:11: note: to match this '('
    while ( int n < 0 || int n > 23);
          ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: declare `n` only once, outside the do-while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare n only once, outside the do-while loop:

```
int n = -1;
do
{
    printf("Enter a positive integer no greater than 23: \n");
    n = get_int();
}
while (n < 0 || n > 23);
```

Comment: can I set n to whatever number I want the first time I declare it? Or do I even have to set it to anything?

Comment: yes, actually, because the `do()` loop will set it to input anyways

Comment: @R_C Yes, at least anything capable of being stored in an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

we never define a variable inside
expressions  like  if or while and For loop
this is only possible in other languages like C++ |;

Comment: Thanks. I use Python, new to C.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the fact that you have:

- Declared `n` inside your while loop (This is not allowed in C89, but is grudgingly allowed in later versions)
- Declared `n` twice in the while section.

The idea of declaration is to show the compiler, that the variable name present is not garbage but is actually a variable. The compiler generally follows fixed rules and does not look for variable names within the while/for loops (this is for optimization purposes). Also the second time that you declared `n` the compiler is now confused as you have stated a variable named `n` already exists.

PS: I believe you wished to say that `n lies within the bounds of 1 and 22` If you wished to say this the correct expression would involve `AND` (`&&`) and not `OR` (`||`) ie, `while ( int n < 0 && int n > 23)`.